# Marriage of Muslim

Tags: nikah, family

Can Muslim marry a cousin or is it haram? What part of quran can I analyse it? I try to understand reading quran but I don't understand.

Comment: What you mean by cousin? It matters a lot whether you mean paternal or maternal...

Comment: No it's not forbidden ..., at least accordin to Shi'ite jurisprudence of which I am aware

Comment: She is maternal, and I like her, but I don't know about marriage. I am a new Muslim. And, sorry for my English.